# What is the source for the information returned by the Get-Printer powershell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, printing

When executing the powershell cmdlet Get-Printer I'm curious about what where it sources its information from. Does it rely on WMI? Does it parse the registry? I've come across situations where the response from Get-Printer differs from the windows devices and printers control panel UI so I thought I would see if anyone knows the source for Get-Printer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output type of `Get-Printer` is `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_Printer`.

You can find out the type name by using `Get-Printer | Get-Member` or reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printer?view=win10-ps).

Hence you can use `Get-CimInstance -Namespace 'root/standardcimv2' -ClassName MSFT_Printer` as an equivalent to `Get-Printer`.